# Datadog transaction duration as metric

Tags: logging, datadog

We have logs from different services with one CustomerID.

```
SERVICE-A. CustomerID: 11. Event: start session. Time: 10:00:00
SERVICE-B. CustomerID: 11. Event: finished session. Time: 10:02:00.
```

I want to know the duration of the session (from beginning to end).
I accumulated these logs into transaction using this guide https://www.datadoghq.com/blog/logs-transactions-queries/

But also I want to get the duration as metric - for monitoring and alerting purposes.
Is it possible to use duration as metric and add it to monitoring?