# How to create monitor/alert based on transaction duration in DataDog?

Tags: monitoring, datadog, observability

DataDog logs can be grouped into transactions and DataDog calculates each transactions duration, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62782910/how-to-calculate-duration-between-logs-in-datadog). [DataDog docs say](https://www.datadoghq.com/blog/logs-transactions-queries/#:%7E:text=By%20adding%20these%20metrics%20to%20your%20query%2C%20you%20can%20surface%20transactions%20that%20show%20you%20where%20problems%2C%20such%20as%20high%20severity%20errors%20or%20latency%2C%20are%20occurring) we can surface transactions with high latency but I cannot find any way to do it. This is what I have so far:
[image]

What I am trying to:

(i) (At least) Sort the transactions in descending order of `DURATION`;

(ii) (Ideally) Create a measure/metric from `DURATION` and set up monitors/alerts based on it.

There is a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73149431/349739) but there are no answers for it.

Any help is appreciated!